# alternate for load function in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this code which runs fine but how ever that is not the problem.

```
  var getContents;

  $('#phramecomp').load(function(){
                $('#phramecomp').contents().find('#dunkindonuts').click(function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    getContents('donuts','dunkin donuts');
                })
                $('#phramecomp').contents().find('#dunkinburgers').click(function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    getContents('burgers','dunkin donuts');
                })
                $('#phramecomp').contents().find('#dunkincake').click(function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    getContents('cake','dunkin donuts');

                })
                $('#phramecomp').contents().find('#dunkinwraps').click(function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    getContents('wraps','dunkin donuts');
                })
                $('#phramecomp').contents().find('#moddonuts').click(function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    getContents('donuts','mad over donuts');
                })
                $('#phramecomp').contents().find('#modpastries').click(function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    getContents('pastries','mad over donuts');
                })

                 getContents= function (type,companyname) {
                     $.ajax({
                         url: 'viewproducts.php',
                         type: 'POST',
                         data: {
                             type: type,
                             companyname: companyname
                         },
                         success: function (contents) {
                             $('#limitpage').html(contents);
                         }
                     })
                 }
                })
```

In this code `phramecomp` is the `iframe` id.

I read about the deprecation of the `load` function.So i thought of removing the `load` function but with the similar function and is not deprecated.What should i remove it with in order to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just listen for the event directly using `.on()`:

```
  $('#phramecomp').on('load', function(){
```

See [the jQuery ticket](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11733#comment:6) that recommended its deprecation.

Comment: `Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.` I still see this in the console.

Comment: That wasn't even part of your question.

Comment: I have selected it as the correct answer but this always comes when ever i use this load method.?